# Page cannot be crawled by Google at all

Tags: google-search-console, wordpress, search-engine-indexing

I am trying to index a page which was set to "discourage search engines to index" until 2021-10-31. Now it's 2021-11-06 and Google does not even try to access the page.

If I use the search console, it get errors it cannot be fetched. Same with the mobile testing tool:

[image: URL is not available to google]

My page meta is content:

```
<meta name='robots' content='max-image-preview:large' />
```

https://page.et/robots.txt

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /wp-admin/
Allow: /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php

Sitemap: https://example.com/wp-sitemap.xml
```

- There was a forward from page.et/robots.txt to page.et/en/robots.txt which I also disabled. In my Chrome it's still cached, but using an incognito tab I can see the robots.txt
- When trying to request the page in Google I see zero evidence of Google trying to access my page, not even the robots.txt - in my web server logs.

Is Google really blocking all requests to my page and storing this persistently for more then 4 days ? Or is there maybe really a technical reasons it does not access my page?

Are there any additional tools to debug this?

Update: In the search console, it displays this:

[image: Index request rejected]

[image: URL is not on Google]

How do I read these reasons?

*Edit 2021-11-07* Same result .. I don't think it's just a caching problem by Google :-( I mostly wonder how I can debug this properly. The output by Google search console does not seem helpful :-(

*Edit:* I am getting some strange errors in Google Pagespeed which I tried to see if Google can access the page at all. Following up eventual server configuration errors here: https://serverfault.com/questions/1082838/pagespeed-cannot-always-access-page-failed-document-request-ssl-certification

Comment: Replace your robots meta with this and try again. To provide a good answer we need some things ruled out. `<meta name='robots' content='index, follow, max-image-preview:large' />`. Make sure it's in the `<head>` of course.

Comment: Do you know if there is a WordPress setting for this? And do I have to wait again several days to try again?

Comment: Via code, header.php (most themes). Codeless route you'd use an SEO plugin like RankMath, Yoast, etc.

Comment: Okay, I can try. I don't use any WordPress SEO Plugins yet and find it very strange that Google does not index a pretty default WordPress site. What can be other reasons?

Comment: Google _should_ index by default but in your case it's not even crawling and you're not blocking it in your robots.txt. You said in the past the site was set to no-index right? This is a quick thing to _rule out_ buggy behavior I have seen in the past. Please make sure all caches are disabled for now. This is not an answer. As of now there are too many unknowns to provide one.

Comment: What is your stack? Would like to know everything. Ex: Ubuntu, Nginx, Cloudflare

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04, Apache 2, Cloudflare DNS but not Cloudflare proxy, WordPress Multisite. The actual URL is https://page.et

Comment: Are other sites on your multi site installation having issues?

Comment: Yes, all sites on the mutli-site installation seem to have that issue

Comment: I forgot to mention mod_security in my stack, but I tried even with disabling that one and it is still not working. Also I would see requests from Google, even if they are blocked by mod_security, in the access log.

Comment: I tried https://support.google.com/webmasters/contact/indexing_issue_form now ...

Comment: On the server what is the output of the following command: `stat -c "%a %n" /var/www/your-site/robots.txt`? Replace `/your-site/` with your sites directory name of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### .Et domain zone NS block Googlebot

The problem is on the side of the .et name servers - they "block" Googlebot.

This Google Support thread reports a problem with indexation with **all** [domains in ".et" zone](https://support.google.com/webmasters/thread/121050229/problem-with-indexation-with-all-domains-in-et-zone-%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%85-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2-et?hl=ru&msgid=123891296)

Comment: Do you have a source for your quote in English?  It would be more useful to others.

Comment: @Trebor translate the page? This is the answer.

Comment: Page translation: "At the moment, I only know that the problem is on the side of the .et nameservers  -  they "block" Googlebot ... Google specialists are trying to contact representatives of NS  .et  to resolve the current situation."

Comment: @MikeCiffone it's completely illegible characters for me.  Can't even find a translate button.

Comment: Wow, that is very interesting. How can a TLD block the Google bot technically? (only the domain is .et, the server is in Germany, and the DNS is cloudflare). We have staff in Ethiopia and might be able to try to contact the telecom there, if Google is not able too

Comment: It seems not be the cause for the full zone? Because searching for *.et in the past 24 hrs gives some results: https://www.google.com/search?q=site:.et&source=lnt&tbs=qdr:d&sa=X&biw=2560&bih=1367&dpr=1 - or maybe it affects only new pages?

Comment: the search results in Google with directive site:*.et/& seems to me too much harmful to unblock for any crawlers.

Comment: @Alex Ethiopia is now in a difficult political and economic situation, there is a military conflict. 

et. domain zone is a big whole with potential dangerous websites ( winner.et, 1xbet.et, bet24.et - betting, casino, gambling, webcams, malware, fishing and even worse..)

I would recommend that you register a domain in a more trusted domain zone, for example .com or .org

Comment: @Trebor The language switcher is at the page footer. You can also use the translation app.

Comment: We target the Ethiopian market, so it is not really an option to use another TLD. Thanks anyway for shedding light on this. I would be interested in the technical details about the block (Is Google blocking .et or is .et blocking Google ?) and who to discuss the unblocking with. I am sure there are lots of "trash" sites in .com as well, that can not be the reason to block a full country's TLD

Comment: .com is an international commercial domain trusted in Google. For organizations it is better to use .org. You can target such domains to the region of promotion (Ethiopia) using Google Webmasrers tool. This will make your site's services available to Google users in your country. The solution to the issue of blocking Googlebot on the .et nameservers side will be long in time.

Comment: Okay, I have time. Do you know how the nameservers block google? Is there a flag or so visible? Or is it on IP level?

Comment: @Alex, A DNS block works by removing the IP address name from the “phonebook” on your server. For example, if you were to block Twitter using a DNS blocker, your server would intentionally forget the name assigned to 199.59.149.165. As a result, blockers disable your server from locating particular web pages. To block whole genres of web pages, like piracy sites, DNS blocking services can set your server to forget large swaths of IP addresses that fit certain criteria. 

List of Googlebot IP addresses
https://developers.google.com/search/apis/ipranges/googlebot.json

Answer (score 1):

okay. Let's be technical. It's really good that you've checked the access log for google accessing your robots. That's important. Our first aim would be to force google to index robots. But before we do it, make sure you actually Allow that page in your robots. Just to override any conflicts there.

Now see this? https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/robots/submit-updated-robots-txt I know, I know, it's trivial, but no, scroll down where it says `If you need to update the cache faster, use the Submit function of the robots.txt Tester.` Use it!

Okay, now our real problem may be not in robots.txt. So that was attempt 1. Let's go to attempt 2.

Do the dofollow meta set up the first comment from Mike suggests. Now take the page G doesn't wanna crawl and add some random query param to it. Like `page.et/blah-blah/?foo=bar&someparam=something` and try submitting it. Your backend will ignore a random query param and serve the same page. From G's perspective, however, it would be a different page. Now I hope G eats it. We're debugging it now.

Now if G eats it, we're one step closer to resolving the issue. Well, even on it's own, it can resolve it, but still, try using... uh... try making sure that on this ?someparam version of the page the canonical is set to the original page with no ?someparam. That would be an interesting way to solve it.

Also, keep monitoring the hits to all three urls from google. They give a lot of insight into G's behavior.

You can... force G to your page by redirecting it from your ?someparam page, hehe. That would be funny to watch, but don't force it yet. It's interesting to see if more civilized ways work.

Comment: I tried adding random query strings, the page can still not be fetched in the search console.

Comment: Which means that it's not cache. It's something different. Have you added the allow to robots.txt prior to testing?

Answer (score 1):

When testing with Google Lighthouse, I receive a network error:  `

> "DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for
> https://page.et/wp-content/plugins/map-block-leaflet/lib/leaflet.markercluster.js.map:
> HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE"`

Additionally, under the Lighthouse Issues tab there's the message:

> A page or script is accessing at least one of navigator.userAgent,
> navigator.appVersion, and navigator.platform. Starting in Chrome 101,
> the amount of information available in the User Agent string will be
> reduced. To fix this issue, replace the usage of navigator.userAgent,
> navigator.appVersion, and navigator.platform with feature detection,
> progressive enhancement, or migrate to navigator.userAgentData. Note
> that for performance reasons, only the first access to one of the
> properties is shown. 1 source leaflet.js:1

I'm thinking you have a Wordpress plugin or piece of code relating to your map that is causing your problem.  It's either being actively blocked or the file is missing.  I tried accessing the file above and received a 404 error from Firefox.

I would disable any plugins and retest.  Also, do you have a firewall or security plugin that could be blocking Google?

Comment: I believe a .map (sourcemap) file is only necessary for debugging into javascript files, or am I wrong?

Comment: I don't believe that is the reason, especially because Google not even tries to load the page, according to the access log - so it should not be caused by a Javascript problem (especially there is not a real one)

Comment: @Alex, you may be correct about your map file, but it appears that at least one of your plugins is calling it.  However, the 404 error could be an indicator of another problem, like something blocking access.